# New Pressure water tank

Tags: water, water-tank, pressure

I replaced my old tank with a new 86-gallon tank. Also replaced pressure switch 30/50. Not getting any water in the house. What might be the cause of this. Also Checked the control box to make sure it was not the deep well pump. My ohms readings were in line for a 1hp pump so that is not my issue. No leaks on any of the pipes either.

Thank you

Comment: Pump working and no leaks, Quite a few pressure switches have a lever that needs to be held down until pressure builds up.

Comment: Please take the [tour], review [https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask] and [edit] your question to provide considerably more detail. Perhaps you forgot to turn the pump power back on, perhaps your pressure switch needs to be held half-way on to start, perhaps you closed a valve you need to open again - but basically you've given very little detail for anything past guessing, so far. Had water stopped before you decided to change the pressure tank?